# Word 2016 separating multi digit footnotes on print

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016, footnote

When printing a document in Word 2016 to PDF, multi digit numbers for footnotes get separated by the footnote text.

So for a foot note that says `12 Source` I'll end up with a footnote that says `1 Source 2` in the PDF. Why does it do that or how can I avoid this?

Examples are included in the following screenshots:

- [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEX0Q.png)
- [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9O7u.png)
- [Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FpcB.png)

If you don't feel like clicking them, here is the first image inlined:

[image: Example 1]

Comment: Unfortunately I can not.It looks like this: 1 coat     2 instead of 12 coat .

Comment: I have taken screenshots but I do not know to upload and send it to you.

Comment: If you have the edit option for the post open, there is a little picture icon you can use to attach and upload screenshot (or press Ctrl+G). Otherwise you could always host it differently e.g. by directly uploading it to Imgur or some other picture hosting service.